# Android textview is overlap with imageview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout file for listview, however the textview's text is overlapped with the imageview. What's wrong with my layout content?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you show some image like what you want and what you got?

Comment: I have tried your layout and I didn't find any problem (except the non-existing `@id/secondLine`). Could you post the screenshot of issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. **Change** the `TextView` width as `wrap_content` and add

Below two lines in that `TextView`

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

and

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon" 
    android:textSize="16sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Just a note for your layout: The `TextView` will overlap the `ImageView` if the `text` is very long.

Comment: @AndrewT. Check my edit `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"` i added

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:contentDescription="TODO"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Example application"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:padding="6dip" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="TextView" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```